# Can you customise your copy and paste in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to copy and paste a formula for over 800 rows. I need the lookup_value of the MATCH to increase by 1 every time and everything else to remain the same. Is it possible to set up a custom copy/paste where I can set the values that need to change?

**What I have**

= IFERROR(IFERROR(CELL("address",INDEX('Sheet 1'!G1:G330,MATCH(D12,'Sheet 1'!G1:G330,0))), CELL("address",INDEX('Sheet 1'!BE1:BE330,MATCH(D12,'Sheet 1'!BE1:BE330,0)))), CELL("address",INDEX('Sheet 1'!DB1:DB330,MATCH(D12,'Sheet 1'!DB1:DB330,0))))

**What Excel gives me**

= IFERROR(IFERROR(CELL("address",INDEX('Sheet 1'!G2:G331,MATCH(D13,'Sheet 1'!G2:G331,0))), CELL("address",INDEX('Sheet 1'!BE2:BE331,MATCH(D13,'Sheet 1'!BE2:BE331,0)))), CELL("address",INDEX('Sheet 1'!DB2:DB331,MATCH(D13,'Sheet 1'!DB2:DB331,0))))

**What I need**

= IFERROR(IFERROR(CELL("address",INDEX('Sheet 1'!G1:G330,MATCH(D13,'Sheet 1'!G1:G330,0))), CELL("address",INDEX('Sheet 1'!BE1:BE330,MATCH(D13,'Sheet 1'!BE1:BE330,0)))), CELL("address",INDEX('Sheet 1'!DB1:DB330,MATCH(D13,'Sheet 1'!DB1:DB330,0))))

Comment: Columns and rows in your formula that you want to stay static, add **`$`** sign infront of them and then drag it down (i.e. if you have `MATCH(D13,'Sheet 1'!BE1:BE330,0)` formula and you only want the row in `D` to change, you will have: **`MATCH($D13,'Sheet 1'!$BE$1:$BE$330,0)`**

Comment: Thank you! That's it working now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specifically:

Your formula needs to be:

```
= IFERROR(IFERROR(CELL("address",INDEX('Sheet 1'!G$1:G$330,MATCH(D12,'Sheet 1'!G$1:G$330,0))), CELL("address",INDEX('Sheet 1'!BE$1:BE$330,MATCH(D12,'Sheet 1'!BE$1:BE$330,0)))), CELL("address",INDEX('Sheet 1'!DB$1:DB$330,MATCH(D12,'Sheet 1'!DB$1:DB$330,0))))
```

Then when you copy/paste is the 1 and 330 will remain as 1 and 330, while the 12 will become 13, then 14, etc